# Can a condition be based on both a selection and a predicate?

Tags: altair

Is it possible to combine a selection and a predicate in a condition? I would like to color points on a scatterplot only if the group is selected and above a certain value.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['Origin'])
color = alt.condition(
    selection & (alt.datum.Miles_per_Gallon > 18),
    alt.Color('Origin:N'),
    alt.value('lightgray')
)

alt.Chart(source).mark_circle().encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color=color,
    tooltip=['Name', 'Origin', 'Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon']
).add_selection(
    selection
)
```

Trying to compound the selection and the predicate raises:

```
Javascript Error: Cannot find a selection named "(datum.Miles_per_Gallon > 18)".
```

The code works with either just the selection or the condition, but not both. The only solution I can think of is layering a scatterplot on top with all the data points below the threshold colored gray. Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I can't think of any way the code you pasted could result in the error you pasted. `alt.datum.value` is of type `GetAttrExpression`, but the error indicates you are using a `>` operator between a `float` and a `Selection`.

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong error, I've changed the example to a reprex with the correct error message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `&` operator does not work properly between a selection and an expression (tracked by [this issue](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/695) in the Altair repository). You can work around this by using the underlying schema object instead:

```python
color = alt.condition(
    alt.LogicalAndPredicate(**{'and': [selection, '(datum.Miles_per_Gallon > 18)']}),
    alt.Color('Origin:N'),
    alt.value('lightgray')
)
```

The resulting chart looks like this when the selection is empty:
[image]